# The argument type 'MyBloc' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MyBloc Function(BuildContext)

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to add **[flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)** to my flutter application. I have Home page and when click on a button in home page Need to Navigation to a different page. Navigation is working without any issue, But When Wrap the the component with a BlocProvider getting below wrror

**The argument type 'MyBloc' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MyBloc Function(BuildContext)'**

This what I have tried so far

My Bloc

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

enum MyEvent {increment, decrement}

class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, int> {
  MyBloc() : super(0);  

  @override
  Stream<int> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
    switch (event) {
      case MyEvent.increment:
        yield state + 1;
        break;
      case MyEvent.decrement:
        yield state - 1;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

In home page I'm calling below function when click on button

```
  Future<void> _routeToTodayTasks() {
    return Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => BlocProvider<MyBloc>(
            create: MyBloc(),
            child: TodayTasks(),
          )));
  }
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?
[image]

Comment: create accepts a function which returns a bloc, not an instance of bloc, so use `(context)=> MyBloc(),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message clearly states, the create argument in `BlocProvider` is accepting a function with syntax `MyBloc Function(BuildContext)`, but instead you are returning an object of your `MyBloc` class directly.

So, returns the bloc object from a function like this:

```
 create: (context) => MyBloc(),
```